# Multi-label classification - ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 5) vs (None, 20))

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

For background, I am following this short guide for **multi-label classification**, wherein I have several final classes for which a prediction can be associated with more than one final class: https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-image-classification-with-neural-network-keras-ddc1ab1afede

Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
Epoch 1/300 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "learn.py", line 124, in <module> 
    model.fit(train, train_labels, epochs=300)
  File "C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 848, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 580, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds) 
  File "C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 627, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 505, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2446, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs) 
  File "C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2777, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs) 
  File "C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2657, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 981, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs) 
  File "C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 441, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 968, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:532 train_step  **
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:205 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:143 __call__    
        losses = self.call(y_true, y_pred)
    C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:246 call        
        return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:1595 binary_crossentropy
        K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits), axis=-1)
    C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4692 binary_crossentropy
        return nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)
    C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py:171 sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
        raise ValueError("logits and labels must have the same shape (%s vs %s)" %

    ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 5) vs (None, 20))
```

**For reference:** these are the outputs of the shapes for train and train_labels:

```
train.shape          <- (66633, 15) 
train_labels.shape   <- (66633, 20)
```

However, I know that the `train_labels.shape` shows 20, but before One Hot Encoding and passing this into `sklearn`'s `train_test_split` function, the head of the labels table is as follows:

```
Movement  Distance  Speed  Delay  Loss 

               1         1     25      0     0
               1         1     25      0     0
               1         1     25      0     0
               1         1     25      0     0
               1         1     25      0     0
```

I am not sure why it has gone from 5 classes suddenly to 20..

The **code** I am using for the model is as follows:

```
## Pre-process ##
# Normalise
sc = MinMaxScaler()
dataset = sc.fit_transform(dataset)
# One-hot encode (OHE)
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
labels = ohe.fit_transform(labels).toarray()
# Split into train and test
train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(dataset, labels, test_size=0.2) #80% train split

## Define model architecture ##

# Declare model format
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='sigmoid')) # Sigmoid for multi-label classification

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

## Fit the model ##
model.fit(train, train_labels, epochs=300)
```

**EDIT:** The dataset and labels are originally `pandas` dataframes.

Comment: so labels is a pandas df with shape (66633,5) ? looking at the first row u reported (1,1,25,0,0) at which class belong to this observation ?

Comment: Yes labels is originally a pandas df with the shape `(83292, 5)` but after the split into train/test, the shape for training **should** become `(66633, 5)`.. For this first row, the first row in the training set should correspond to that label.

Comment: sorry I don't understand... this first row is Movement, Distance, Speed, Delay or Loss ?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani it is a multi-label classification problem. The first row can correspond to movement, distance, speed, delay **and/or** loss.

Comment: I know this but I expect that it should be (1,1,1,0,0) for example which means that this row is Movement, Distance, and Speed... 25 is misleading

Comment: @MarcoCerliani the (1,1,25,0,0) is **before** one-hot encoding. the vector you describe is what is there after.

Comment: ok, so it's correct to say that (1,1,25,0,0)  is (1,1,1,0,0) and that the first row belong to Movement, Distance, and Speed?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Perhaps the problem here is I one-hot encoded the whole labels data frame. Whereas I need to do it for each individual column, as they can belong to multiple classes?

Comment: I think I may have to use `MultiLabelBinarizer` for my one-hot encoding

Comment: yes, the problem is the one-hot encoder... I suggest you this simple trial (before train test split) labels = np.where(labels.values>0, 1, 0) ... in this way you are reporting all in 0-1 and u don't need other encoders

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I used the `MultiLabelBinarizer` and the problem I get is the input shape now.. The labels shape is `(5, 18)` but the dataset shape is `(83292, 15)` so it wont go into the `train_test_split` function.

Comment: give a trial on what I say u before... labels = np.where(labels.values>0, 1, 0) (before train test split) and remove all encoder/binarizer

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Thanks it now fits in and starts the model.. However it is giving me always 100% accuracy..? Is this a problem?